# Spark approach for equation involving pairwise distance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a piece of pseudocode that I've been trying to implement in Spark (currently using Scala, but happy to use another language if needed) for about a week and am utterly stuck. The section of pseudocode that's causing me issues is (apologies for the image, but w/o MathOverflow's LaTeX option, it seemed the clearest): [pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tlo4M.png)

- Each row contains an `id1`, `id2`, `ob`, `x`, and `y`.
- I'm using `Window` to partition by (`id1`, `id2`) with each window having multiple (`x`: Integer, `y`: Integer, and `ob`: Double) which constitute a cell or `c`.
- The loop is for `k = 1 ... m` with `m` being the number of rows in the window.
- Order of the rows does not matter for my purposes (the `st` value will be affected, but past work suggests it doesn't have an observable difference in the final result).
- All previously calculated rows with `st` > 0 are part of `K`. Since `st` >= 0, it seems safe to include all previously calculated rows.
- `alpha` is a fixed parameter.
- `Dis_grid` is currently a euclidian distance UDF between the `x` and `y` coordinates by row, but it can be a different distance measure if that would make implementation easier.

I'm not able to figure out how to:

- Assign the first row in a window a distinct value.
- Use the `st` of previously calculated rows to calculate the `st` for the next row.
- Calculate individual pairwise distances between rows to be part of the `st` formula.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does each group of cells end up with a single `st` value? (Presumably so, else order would matter?)

Comment: Yes, each group of cells does end up w/ a single `st` value. The order will still affect the order of that value, but prior work with the approach suggests empirically there's no observable difference in the final results of the overall method from shuffling the order in a group of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a hard time following precisely what you're trying to do (I think order *does* matter within a group/window), so this may not be right, but these are my thoughts. First off, I think this will be *a lot* easier to do thinking in terms of `Dataset` operations rather than `DataFrame` operations. (If you want to do this in the DataFrame world, I think you want to look at User Defined Aggregation Functions (UDAFs).) Since a `DataFrame` is nothing but `Dataset[Row]`, it's all equivalent, but I'm going to define a `Cell` case class and work with a `Dataset[Cell]` to simplify things, so please indulge me.

```
case class Cell(id1: Int, id2: Int, ob: Double, x: Int, y: Int)
```

Imagine we have a `Dataset[Cell]`, call it `ds`. We want to group it by pairs `(id1,id2)` and then apply some function (call if `f`) on each group and end up with a `Dataset[(Cell, Double)]`. (I think this is what you want. I'm having trouble seeing how order of rows/cells within a group does not matter in this case.) This amounts to

```
ds.groupByKey(c => (c.id1, c.id2).flatMapGroups(f)
```

So what's `f`? It needs to compute `st` for each cell in the group. If I'm understanding properly, the summation works like this: for cell `i`, sum `st(j) * alpha^dist(i, j)` for all `j < i`. Subtract that sum from the cell's observation and max with 0 to get `st`. Assuming you have a function `dist` to compute the distance between two cells, as a function all the cells, the previously computed `st`s and the cell `c`, the summation term works out to be:

```
def stSum(cells: List[Cell], sts: List[Double], c: Cell): Double =
    sts.zipWithIndex.map{ case (st, l) => 
        st * math.pow(alpha, dist(c, cells(l)))
    }.sum
```

Then for a cell `c`, `st` is `math.max(0, c.ob - stSum(cells, sts, c))`, where `cells` is all the cells in the group, and `sts` is a list of the `st` values for the "earlier" cells. We can then compute the (ordered) list of `st`s with a `foldLeft`:

```
cells.foldLeft(List()){ case (sts, c) =>
  sts :+ math.max(0, c.ob - stSum(cells, sts, c))    
}
```

We can then assemble `f`:

```
def f(key: (Int, Int), cellIterable: Iterable[Cell]): List[(Cell, Double)] = {
  val cells = cellIterable.toList
  val sts = cells.foldLeft(List()){ case (stAcc, c) =>
    stAcc :+ math.max(0, c.ob - stSum(cells, stAcc, c))    
  }
  cells.zip(sts)
}
```

We need to convert `cellIterable` to a list because we need to access its elements by index, so we need a type that supports that. It's generally faster in Scala to prepend to a list rather than append, and it would be possible to build up the list of `st`s in reverse, but it'd require some index juggling. One final note is that the `f` in `flatMapGroups` takes tuples and the `f` I wrote just above doesn't, so you'd end up with

```
ds.groupByKey(c => (c.id1, c.id2).flatMapGroups(Function.tupled(f))
```

Comment: First, I have to say thank you for the amazing response; it is so much more explanatory and complete than I could've ever expected. Indeed, the order would affect the `st` value, but empirically in past work, it has shown not to affect the final result. I shall edit the question for future clarification. I shall work to implement your suggestion today, and report back how it goes. Again, thank you.